# fibbonacci sequence even term sum?

Tags: c++, c++11

Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...

By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int i =1;
int j =2;
int k = 0;
while (k<4000000)
{
    k = i +j;
    i = k+j;
    j=i +k;
}
cout << i <<endl;
cout << j << endl;
cout << k << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Am I even doing this correctly? Why am I getting three different nu

Comment: What do you want to ask?You need us to help you check the code?This is a bad question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the sum of even terms in Fibonacci sequence, you can use a function that uses [recursion](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/39170/), but that will take more time than your code since recursion will compute the Fibonacci for each element and won't store the Fibonacci of the previous numbers.

But if you want to use your code, this will be faster for the compilation to your process, but I thing your code must be like this.

```
int even=2;
while (k<4000000 && i<4000000 && j<4000000)
{
    k = i+j;      //3 13 55    i,j and k computes Fibonacci 
    i = k+j;      //5 21 89    of sequence of numbers so  
    j = i+k;      //8 34 144   they must differ :)
    if(k%2==0)even+=k;
    if(i%2==0)even+=i;
    if(j%2==0)even+=j;
}
   if(k>=4000000 && k%2==0)even-=k;
   if(j>=4000000 && j%2==0)even-=j;
   if(i>=4000000 && i%2==0)even-=i;
cout<<"even sum equals"<<even;
}
```

Comment: Starting from 1 and 2, you know exactly which numbers will be even: j, no need to check.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I didn't understand your point, could you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

You can this code to find desired output

```
int evenFibSum(int limit)
{
if (limit < 2)
    return 0;

// Initialize first two even prime numbers
// and their sum
long long int ef1 = 0, ef2 = 2;
long long int sum = ef1 + ef2;

// calculating sum of even Fibonacci value
while (ef2 <= limit)
{
    // get next even value of Fibonacci sequence
    long long int ef3 = 4*ef2 + ef1;

    // If we go beyond limit, we break loop
    if (ef3 > limit)
        break;

    // Move to next even number and update sum
    ef1 = ef2;
    ef2 = ef3;
    sum += ef2;
}

return sum;
}
```